# LCD screen not working with Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: raspbian, hdmi, screen

I've got Raspberry Pi 3B+ and [this screen](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD) and I tried to plug it up, but it's not working. OS configurations I tried:

1. just Raspbian
2. Waveshare drivers on same Raspbian
3. some random drivers on same Raspbian
4. Waveshare Raspbian Version
5. Waveshare drivers on Waveshare Raspbian Version
6. some random drivers on Waveshare Raspbian Version

Every configuration has been done with usage of this config.

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

Without usage of `Waveshare drivers` screen had few tiny, green lines, but interesting thing is only touch has been working with `Waveshare drivers`, but not screen.

I consider that screen might be broken, but I don't want to unnecessarily send it back to shop, so I'm looking for your help. Is there anything else that can help to connect my screen?

Comment: connect it to a device with HDMI output, either a PC or a video player of some type

Comment: Wiki says: `Note: This product can only work on a Raspberry Pi but not work on a PC. That is, if the HDMI of the LCD is connected to the HDMI on a PC, the LCD doesn't display anything.` I think it's not possible.

Comment: First question is if you have connected it correctly. You could post pictures.

Comment: If you watch [this video](https://youtu.be/l8JJeI0ip-4), you can see that you can't connect it wrong if you are using original HDMI connector.

Comment: I have one of these and can at least confirm it really does only work with a Pi. Why it's not working on your Pi, I couldn't say. I think I tested with a 2 B+.